# Can past simple fit too

Tags: past-tense

then he remembered  what had happened at the weekend. On Saturday afternoon his new car
(disappear) from the road in front of his house. Sam called the police but ten minutes later his brother drove up.

I think past perfect  had disappeared must fit  here but what about past simple? . There is a date so we know that it happens before the headteacher came in very angry on Monday so it could fit too
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/106820893/Mix-Tense-in-Context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use past simple, but past perfect is better. It establishes the earlier fact that was the reason for the past event of his calling the police.

In informal speech, simple past would still be understood.

Comment: 'he remembered" is past tense, what had happened at the weekend took place earlier, like Jack said.